# how to post an url and to retrive the website contents using perl

Tags: perl

I want to get a solution for how to post one particular url and to retrieve the content. Is it possible with perl ? let it be a website where we are searching for one particular id, and we are supposed to get the associated information tagged to that id.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP.pm

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $server_endpoint = "";

# set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');


my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print "HTTP GET error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP GET error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
```

Or you can do this way also using[**LWP::Simple**](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Simple.pm)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.example.com';
my $content = get $url or die "Unable to get $url\n";
print $content;
```

Comment: Difficult to do a POST with LWP::Simple.